# Firefox throws error 0x80004005 when working with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, canvas

Sometimes I some errors like this one when I'm working with canvas on Firefox:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure
>   code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.lineWidth]"  nsresult: "0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   media/js/canvas/Rectangle.js ::  :: line 34"  data: no]

It happens when i'm working with more than 5 canvas elements, on a for loop. The function what creates them is this:

```
function addCanvas(id) {
var canvas = document.getElementById(id);

if (canvas == null) {
    $('#content').append(
        '<canvas id="' + id + '" width="' + workAreaWidth +'" height="' 
            + workAreaHeight + '"></canvas>'
    );

    canvas = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
} else {
    canvas = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, workAreaWidth, workAreaHeight);
}   

return canvas;
}
```

The for loop is in another function.

What happens is that not all the canvas elements are updated. I guess cause of the exception.

I can't post the code of the place where it exactly fails, cause it fails randomly in many places, always with the same error.

The Firefox version is 9.0, but also happened on 8.0.1. I didn't test it on previous releases. My operating system is Mac Snow Leopard. I guess it will help. It doesn't fail on Chrome or Safari,

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is a 'for bucle'?  (Did you mean 'for loop'?)

Comment: Yeah, sorry... i'm not english. Ill edit the post to correct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These error messages are confusing to the uninitiated, but there's a lot of information packed into them.  The important parts are:

> Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.lineWidth]

Ignore the hexadecimal number: this is telling you that the accessor `nsIDOMRenderingContext2D.lineWidth` returned a generic failure code (`NS_ERROR_FAILURE`) rather than a line width.  `nsIDOMRenderingContext2D` is the internal name of the C++ class that implements the object you get back from `getContext("2d")` on a canvas element.

> location: "JS frame :: media/js/canvas/Rectangle.js :: :: line 34"

The call from JavaScript into the C++ method that failed is at line 34 of `media/js/canvas/Rectangle.js`.  That's your code.  That is *not*, however, the code that you quoted, but maybe we can figure out what's wrong by looking at the code for the accessor that failed: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/canvas/src/nsCanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp#3180

```
nsresult
nsCanvasRenderingContext2D::GetLineWidth(float *width)
{
    if (!EnsureSurface())
        return NS_ERROR_FAILURE;

    gfxFloat d = mThebes->CurrentLineWidth();
    *width = static_cast<float>(d);
    return NS_OK;
}
```

Okay, so the only way that can fail is if `EnsureSurface` fails.  *That* is defined at http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/canvas/src/nsCanvasRenderingContext2D.cpp#1154 and I'm not going to quote it here because it's huge and has a whole bunch of ways it can fail.  However, it looks to me like one of your canvas elements is either not properly defined, or is not being given a chance to initialize itself (i.e. you need to allow the event loop to run).

**EDIT:** Concrete advice: Change the function you quoted to be like this:

```
function addCanvas(id, continuation) {
    if (document.getElementById(id) === null) {
        $('#content').append(
            '<canvas id="' + id + '" width="' + workAreaWidth +'" height="' 
            + workAreaHeight + '"></canvas>'
        );
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
        canvas.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        canvas.clearRect(0, 0, workAreaWidth, workAreaHeight);
        continuation(canvas);
    }, 0);
}
```

You'll also need to change all callers to match.  I do not guarantee that this will work, but it's the most plausible thing I can think of.

Comment: I didn't expect such a huge answer lol I'll look the file, to see if i can see anything in it and figure out how can it fail. I'll tell something you if i found anything or if i don't, thanks right now ;)

By the way, i told in the question that its not only in the lineWidth function where fails, this is why i didn't posted the code. Sometimes it fails anywhere, mostly in the getContext line.

Comment: Ok, looked the whole function and i can't certainly tell where it comes from. The weird thing is that with a few elements it works ok. with more than ten, not an especific number, it isn't. But just sometimes. Maybe it's just a browser bug, but there's too much code to look at.

Comment: I have added something to try.  I can't promise that this is the problem, but it has a decent chance of working.

Comment: Not working either. I thinked too it was because it didn't have enough time to discover the new element or something like that, but it seems is not the case. I also tried to reuse already existing canvas elements, but with no success. I think I'll stop worrying and use chrome lol

Comment: The most likely reason for EnsureSurface to fail on Windows with hardware acceleration enabled is if your canvas is larger than the texture size on your GPU.  What are the sizes of your canvases, if you're on Windows?

Comment: I'm on Mac, and yeah, they are large. For the tests, i'm using 1287x724 in all the canvas i use. I didn't test if it fails in other operating systems, i have also a Xubuntu / Windows pc, i'll try to work on there too.

Comment: In Linux, all works great. I guess it's a problem with Firefox for Mac.